# Stuck: Counting Problem..Prove that among any 3 integers...

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that among any 3 integers there are always two whose difference is divisible by 2.

Comment: Can you show some effort, i.e. what ides have you tried so far?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236235/discrete-math-counting/236236#236236

Comment: Not if  2 or more of them can be the same!

Answer (score 6):

HINT: Is the difference of two even numbers divisible by $2$? What about the difference of two odd numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Assume your integers are $x_1<x_2<x_3$. If both $x_2-x_1$ and $x_3-x_2$ are odd, then $x_3-x_1=(x_3-x_2)+(x_2-x_1)$ is a sum of two odd numbers and therefore even.